# TypeError: Employees.find is not a function from meteor withTracker

Tags: reactjs, meteor

First used createContainer to subscribe the data but it throws the error called :

```
Uncaught TypeError: CreateContainer is not a function 

react-meteor-data: React higher-order component for reactively tracking Meteor data 

Warning - createContainer was deprecated in react-meteor-data@0.2.13. Use withTracker instead
```

Then changed to withTracker but getting error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Employees.find is not a function
```

Employee_list.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Employees from '../../imports/collections/employees';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

const EmployeeList = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return(
        <div>
            <div className = "employee-list">
                Employee list
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withTracker ( () => {

    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('employees');
    //return { employeesd: Employees.find({}).fetch() };
    return {
        listLoading: !handle.ready(),
        tasks: Employees.find({}).fetch(),
      };
})( EmployeeList );
```

Employees is my mongodb collection

employees.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';    
export const Employees = new Mongo.Collection('employees');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use named export:

```
export const Employees = new Mongo.Collection('employees');
```

but try to use default export:

```
import Employees from '../../imports/collections/employees';
```

**Fix:**

```
import { Employees } from '../../imports/collections/employees';
```

or

```
const Employees = new Mongo.Collection('employees');
export default Employees;
```